# How to get mean from image collection in numerical format?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have some GEE code that works fine in the code editor and it plots a chart like this: It has this image collection called 'toplot' and you pass it to the UI chart function and it plots the chart for you. It has 45 bands, you pass the region of interest and means of all images in the collection are plotted in the chart. This is the code that does the job:

```
var annual_prof = ui.Chart.image.series({

imageCollection: toplot,

region: ROI,

reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),

scale: scale,

xProperty: 'system:time_start',

});

annual_prof.setChartType("ColumnChart");

annual_prof.setOptions({

title: (Adm+'-Avg NDVI Anomalies in the 12 months\nto: '+lastdatetext),

hAxis: {format:'', title: '8 days period'},

vAxis: {title: 'Anomaly %'},

lineWidth: 2,

pointSize: 1,

legend: 'none',

series : {

0 : {color : 'darkgreen'}}

});

print(annual_prof)
```

I need to get those means in an array form so that I can use it to plot the chart on the webapp. The UI functions don't work in Python and JavaScript APIs. So after reading the documentation I tried this:

```
function get_mean(d){
  return d.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), ROI);
}

var nums = toplot.map(get_mean);
print(nums)
```

But this gives me an error:

> Collection.map: A mapped algorithm must return a Feature or Image.

How can I get these numbers as an array or any other numerical form using GEE functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this worked:

```
var res = toplot.map(function(image) {
  var reduced = image.reduceRegion({geometry: ROI, 
                                    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                                    crs: 'EPSG:4326', 
                                    scale: scale})
  return image.set('mean', reduced);
});
var vals = res.aggregate_array('mean');
print(vals);
```